# Как добавить свой класс в метки на яндекс карте

Tags: javascript, api, яндекс-карты

есть следующая проблема
Создаю обычную яндекс карту, на которую вывожу метки станций метро.
Метка представляет собой обычную пнг картинку.
Вопрос в том, можно ли как то при инициализации меток, добавлять свой кастомный класс на её обёртку?

```
var placemark = new ymaps.Placemark(
        [station.latitude, station.longitude],
        {
            balloonContent: `
                ...             
            `,
        }, {
            iconLayout: 'default#image',
            iconImageHref: icon,
            iconColor: station.line_hex_color,
            iconImageSize: [16, 16],
            iconImageOffset: [-8, -8],
            balloonPanelMaxMapArea: 'Infinity'
            *CLASS: 'MYCUSTOMCLASS'*
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Вроде только так:
iconLayout: 'default#image' => iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent' и задать iconContentLayout  https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/